# Export function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, module, typescript

I have a `.ts` file with a module and a function outside module like this:

```
$(function () {
   populate()
});

function populate() {
...
}

module portfolio.charts {
   export function foo(){
   ...
   }
}
```

Using Typescript compiler command `tsc --declaration` the declaration file is created. This `.d.ts` file contains the following code:

```
 function populate(): void;
 module portfolio.charts {
       function foo(): void;
 }
```

Why `populate()` function and `portfolio.charts` module are exported? I thought it was necessary the keyword `export` to export a function or a module. If I add the `d.ts` file as a dependency on another file I can use all functions and the module. Can I declare them private? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TypeScript specification is a bit dry on this, so here are some examples.

**Example 1**

```
module MyModule {
    class MyClass {
        myFunction() {
            alert('Test');
        }
    }

    function myOtherFunction() {
        alert('Test Again');
    }
}
```

In this example, `MyModule` is a global module (it isn't inside of any other module) so this *will* appear in the definition file. `MyClass`,`myFunction` and `myOtherFunction` are invisible in the definition:

```
module MyModule {
}
```

So to make something visible in your declaration, it either...

1. Needs to be in the global scope, like `MyModule` or like `populate` in your example, or
2. Needs to be prefixed with the `export` keyword

In your example, point 1 applies.